# List of all passenger airlines with regular flights to anywhere in New Zealand

Tags: data-request, public-transport

I am looking for a list of all airline companies that have flights to New Zealand, from a foreign country.

Only regular passenger flights, currently active.

List must be free to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many commercial sites that will provide this info, but for a CC license I'd use the data from the NZ government site: [transport.govt.nz](http://www.transport.govt.nz/air/internationalairservices/internationalairlinelicensing/internationalairlinesservingnewzealand/).

[image]

The license is [CC 3.0 BY NZ](http://www.transport.govt.nz/copyright-and-disclaimer/) ([details](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/nz/)).

Comment: For NZ domestic scheduled airlines, I would go to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_passenger_airlines#AP_N

Answer (score 1):

I compiled this list from information found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport

```
Air New Zealand
Air Tahiti Nui
Air Vanuatu
Aircalin
Cathay Pacific
China Airlines
China Eastern Airlines
China Southern Airlines
Emirates
Fiji Airways
Hawaiian Airlines
Jetconnect
Jetstar Airways
Korean Air
LAN Airlines
Malaysia Airlines
Qantas
Singapore Airlines
Thai Airways International
Virgin Australia
Virgin Samoa
```

Other airports might have other airlines, but most should be here.

Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License.